# Search any combination of words or characters using searchDisplay controller in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Hi I have a master array that populates the tableview and I have a filtered array for the search results. Both of these work fine using the below method. My tableview and search display array is working well except for the below issue under this code block.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
```

{

```
[self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.



for (product *new in parserData)
{

    //Description scope
   if ([scope isEqualToString:@"Description"]) 

    {
        NSRange result = [new.description rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];

        if (result.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:new];
        }
    }


    //Product scope
    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"Product"])

    {
        NSRange result = [new.item rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];

        if (result.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:new];
        }
    }
}
```

}

What I would like to achieve is this. I have an Item in the master array called **LMD-2451 TD Professional 3D LCD Monitor**. I can search for **TD Professional**, **TD Pro**, **TD** and it returns the correct item mentioned above using any case. However if I search **Pro TD** it doesn't show any result. The problem I face is the user may not know the order the product title or description might be? So I would need to implement something that would do this logically. I am really stuck with what to do.

For reference

NSMutableArray *parserData; // Complete main full Array
NSMutableArray  *filteredListContent; // Array for the Search-results

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `componentsSeperatedByString:@" "` on your search string to split it into (in your example) an array of 2 strings, `@"Pro"` and `@"TD"`. Then loop through the array using the `rangeOfString:` check that all the components in the array are found in `new.item`.

```
//Product scope
if ([scope isEqualToString:@"Product"])
{
    // Split into search text into separate "words"
    NSArray * searchComponents = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
    BOOL foundSearchText = YES;

    // Check each word to see if it was found
    for (NSString * searchComponent in searchComponents) {
        NSRange result = [new.item rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
        foundSearchText &= (result.location != NSNotFound);
    }

    // If all search words found, add to the array
    if (foundSearchText)
    {
        [self.filteredListContent addObject: new];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Ashley I get your concept but I am struggling to work out how I might implement this. Do I first need to split up the parserData array? Would you have a brief example?

Comment: Can anyone further help me with this?

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry for the delay!

Comment: Ashley you are the man! Thanks so much seems really obvious when you know how. I had to change only one part for it to work and that was replace rangeOfString:searchText to rangeOfString:searchComponent.. All working perfectly I can't thank you enough if you PM me your email addy I will gladly send you a small gift for your help! :-)

Comment: @AlexMcPherson - your thanks is reward enough. Glad to be able to help.

Comment: Hey Ashley sorry to trouble you. The above code is working great however I have noticed that in searching td then (space) or pro then (space) the results disappear until I start to enter the next first character of the the next word i.e td(Space)p if searching td pro if that makes sense. The search is fine after entering the first charter of the second word after space. Struggling to figure that bit out. Thanks

Comment: If your searchString is "td ", then the two components are "rd" and "" - searching for "" presumably returns NO; To handle this case, just trim off the whitespace before searching `string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]`

Comment: Mate you really are the man I got it sorted thanks so much AGAIN! Alex